# how to capture ip camera with ASP .net MVC2 ( C# )

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-2, camera

I want to capture IP camera image using asp.net MVC2 with c#. Could you please guide
me to some articles on how capture the IP camera. please please

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It depends on a lot of factors like which camera and if the manufacturer provides a SDK with the camera. 
If you provide those details, it will be easy for people to help you more.

But I found a link which I guess might be helpful to you to some extent.
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15537/Camera-Vision-video-surveillance-on-C

Comment: Also be specific as to why you are specifying MVC2. Is there any issue that you are facing?